# How would i create a statement in which i effect 2 different variables in c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm creating a game and a script that i have seems fine but is coming up with 2 compile errors, Here's the script

```
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C) && movementSpeed = 6.5f)
    {
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        movementSpeed = crouchWalkSpeed;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.C) && movementSpeed = 3)
    {
        transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
        movementSpeed = 6.5f;
    }
```

And there is also a

```
public float movementSpeed = 6.5f;
float crouchWalkSpeed = 3;
```

So I dont see the problem , however the errors say:

---

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0019  Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'float'  First person game.CSharp    C:\Users\desha\Documents\First person game\Assets\Scripts\FirstPersonController.cs  52  Active

---

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0019  Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'float'  First person game.CSharp    C:\Users\desha\Documents\First person game\Assets\Scripts\FirstPersonController.cs  57  Active

Comment: You have both a boolean check and a float = check in the if statement.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a single `=` (the assignment operator), you'll wanna use two `==` (the comparison operator) in your `if` statement.

Something like this:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C) && movementSpeed == 6.5f)
```

And this:

```
if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.C) && movementSpeed == 3)
```